# jQuery hoverIntent: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, syntax

I'm using Brian Cherne's `hoverIntent.js` plugin for a project.  It's a great plugin but it seems to be broken in jQuery 1.7.1.

I'm trying to debug it but I'm not the most ace javascripter out there.  Can anyone tell me what I might need to look for in his code to fix the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined`

That's what my Chrome console tells me.  I'm just not sure what to change.

There is the following line of code in the plugin which contains `apply` in the string

`return cfg.over.apply(ob,[ev])}else{pX=cX;pY=cY;ob.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){compare(ev,ob)},cfg.interval)}};`

**EDIT**

I should post the link to Brian's full commented code.  It's here: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.js

**EDIT 2**

My script is as follows

```
//#nav-main dropdown effects                
$('#nav-main ul li').hoverIntent(function () {
   $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideToggle('500');
});
```

Comment: thank you for all the error messages. but basically we need your script code

Comment: @micha - edited the question to include it

Comment: It's not the same. hoverIntent prevents this effect from happening (http://dreamstarstudios.com/screencasts/2011-12-04_0509.swf).  Without `hoverIntent` the dropdowns (since there are many of them) rapidly queue as you hover across.  If there were ONE dropdown then your suggestion would be good, but with many, `hoverIntent` is better.

Comment: @micha watch the video to see the issue

Comment: That works, thanks!  You can post as an answer if you want the reputation for answering it.

Comment: Please mark as best answer the one below if it helped you...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically hoverIntent requires two functions or one object.

If you put in just one function, it will try to use your function as object and you can't apply a function! So use:

```
$('#nav-main ul li').hoverIntent(function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideToggle('500');
}, function(){});
```

Comment: There's nothing like modesty... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one object instead of two functions, but without "out" property you would have same error. I did. Adding "out" fixes it in a same way as @noob already answered, just with different syntax, so it might help someone.

```
$('#nav-main ul li').hoverIntent({
  over: function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideToggle('500');
  },
  out: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with 'parallax' plugin.
I changed jQuery librery version to `*jquery-1.6.4*` from `*jquery-1.10.2*.`
And error cleared.